# Js ошибка Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, стек

Реализовываю алгоритм быстрой сортировки, но она работает только когда элементов меньше чем +-3000. Если элементов больше - вылезает эта ошибка. Условие возврата есть, все работает правильно. В чем проблема и как ее решить? Вот код:

```js
function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    tf = 0;
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
function getBaseLog(x, y) {
    return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
}
function check_sort(array){
    var flag = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
            flag = false;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
function default_sort(array){
    var flag = true;
    while(flag){
        flag = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                flag = true;
                var tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
function bubblesort(array){
    var flag = true;
    var k = 0;
    var array_length = array.length;
    var steps = Math.floor(array_length/100);
    const time_start= new Date().getTime();
    while(flag){
        flag = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
            if (array[i] > array[i + 1]) {
                flag = true;
                var tmp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    const time_end = new Date().getTime();
    var ms = time_end - time_start;
    console.log("Bubblesort - " + check_sort(array));
    return ms;
}
function selection(array){
    const time_start= new Date().getTime();
    var fixed = 0;
    var array_length = array.length;
    var steps = Math.floor(array_length/100);
    while (fixed < array.length - 1){
        var exchange = fixed;
        for (var i = fixed + 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            if(array[exchange] > array[i]){
                exchange = i; 
            }
        }
        if(exchange != fixed){
            var temp = array[fixed];
            array[fixed] = array[exchange];
            array[exchange] = temp;
        }
        fixed++;
    }
    const time_end = new Date().getTime();
    var ms = time_end - time_start;
    console.log("Selection - " + check_sort(array));
    return ms;
}
function shell(array){
    var step = array.length;
    const time_start= new Date().getTime();
    var array_length = array.length;
    var k = 0;
    while (step > 1){
        k++;
        step = Math.floor(step/2);
        for (var i = 0; i < step; i++) {
            var tmpray = [];
            for(var p = i; p <= array.length - 1; p += step){
                tmpray.push(array[p]);
            }
            tmpray = default_sort(tmpray);
            var j = 0;
            for(var p = i; p <= array.length - 1; p += step){
                array[p] = tmpray[j];
            j++;
            }
        }
    }
    const time_end = new Date().getTime();
    var ms = time_end - time_start;
    console.log("Shell - " + check_sort(array));
    return ms;
}
var mrg_steps;
var mrg_max;
var mrg_k;
function merge_recursive(array){
    mrg_k += 1;
    if(array.length > 1){
        var array_1 = array.slice(0, Math.floor((array.length)/2));
        var array_2 = array.slice(Math.floor((array.length)/2), array.length);
        array = default_sort(merge_recursive(array_1).concat(merge_recursive(array_2)));
    }
    return array;
}
function merge(array){
    mrg_max = array.length*2;
    mrg_steps = Math.floor(mrg_max/100);
    mrg_k = 1;
    const time_start= new Date().getTime();
    if(array.length > 1){
        var array_1 = array.slice(0, Math.floor((array.length)/2));
        var array_2 = array.slice(Math.floor((array.length)/2), array.length);
        array = default_sort(merge_recursive(array_1).concat(merge_recursive(array_2)));
    }
    const time_end = new Date().getTime();
    var ms = time_end - time_start;
    console.log("Merge - " + check_sort(array));
    return ms;
}
var k = 0;
function quicksort_recursive(start, end, array){
    k++;
    var i = start + 1;
    var j = end;
    var fixed = start;
    while(1){
        while(array[fixed] > array[i] && i < end){
            i++;
        }
        while(array[j] >= array[fixed] && j > start){
            j--;
        }
        if(i < j){
            var tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }
        else {
            var tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[fixed];
            array[fixed] = tmp;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(j > start) quicksort_recursive(start, j, array);
    if(i < end) quicksort_recursive(i, end, array);
    return;
}
function quicksort(array){
    const time_start= new Date().getTime();
    var start = 0;
    var end = array.length - 1;
    var i = start + 1;
    var j = end;
    var fixed = start;
    while(1){
        while(array[fixed] > array[i] && i < end){
            i++;
        }
        while(array[j] >= array[fixed] && j > start){
            j--;
        }
        if(i < j){
            var tmp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = tmp;
        }
        else {
            var tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[fixed];
            array[fixed] = tmp;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(j > start) quicksort_recursive(start, j, array);
    if(i < end) quicksort_recursive(i, end, array);

    const time_end = new Date().getTime();
    var ms = time_end - time_start;
    console.log("Quick - " + check_sort(array));
    return ms;
}
var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 9000; i++) {
    array.push(getRandomIntInclusive(-200000, 200000));
}
console.log(bubblesort(array));
console.log(selection(array));
console.log(shell(array));
console.log(merge(array));
console.log(quicksort(array));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116049/discussion-on-question-by-shumik-ua-js--maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В общем, из-за выбора в качестве pivot первого элемента, вы попадаете на худший случай при отсортированном массиве на входе.

В итоге, каждый элемент порождает развилку и длина стека стремится к размеру задачи = N.
Каждый вызов отнимает некоторое количество памяти, и в итоге, в моём браузере стек заканчивается на глубине=6987.